# how do i uninstall a progam from linux which isnot present in package list?

Tags: linux

i am completely new to linux.I am running linux mint 15 (cinnamon).I installed some programs which were no present in package list.These were the programs with .run extension.Please tell me how to uninstall them.

Comment: Depending on how good the `run`-file is written, there might be an uninstall option. Try something similar to `package.run --help`.

Comment: Can you tell us what run file?

Comment: If you're lucky the .run file installed the software to /opt or /usr/local in this case you can simply go through every file and directory in /opt and /usr/local and delete it if it belongs to the installed program.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sad to say but there's usually no good way to remove files that got added to the system through .run files. You can try searching for files that have a similar "created" or "modified" date as when you initially installed it. If you're really concerned and have tons of time to spare, you could also create a clean VM of the same distribution, add it to a SCM (e.g. git repo or some filesystem that supports diffing), execute the same .run file(s), and then check for filesystem changes that you undo on the original machine.

Edit: A slightly easier way might be chrooting in a source-controlled directory and executing the original .run files but there's a chance that the .run files might not behave the same since the normal directories may not be there.